# Gmail: make a rule so emails are not send to specific email address

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have an email address on Gmail (E.G: john.doe@gmail.com)
In that mailbox, I also receive emails (forwarded) from an email work address (E.G: john.doe@work.be). This is an Outlook Exchange box and all incoming emails are forwarded to the Gmail address.

There are some emails that are send to my private email address at Gmail that are about the work.
Is it possible to create a filter that searches for emails that are not send to my work (in either To, or CC), so I can forward them to my work address?